# How to disable app icon left click context menu in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to wpf developing. I used an icon in the metro window & want to disable context menu showing when doing left mouse click. I already done this for mouse right click context menu. But got stucked for icons. It would be really grate if anyone can help me. Thanx.

This is xaml code..

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Height="800" Width="1200" Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded"
    ShowIconOnTitleBar="True"
    ShowTitleBar="True" Icon="sign-check-icon.png"
    ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False" 
   WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" IsCloseButtonEnabled="False" IsMinButtonEnabled="False">
```

The requirement is not to resize or minimize the application. I can disable it by using 'ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False" '. But after I use a app icon again it has enabled for left click of the app icon..

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Show us some code!

Comment: I have updated my question with the xaml code. Thanx